# Moodle join tables without raw SQL query

Tags: php, pdo, moodle, moodle-api

I am new to the Moodle world. I want to make inner join 2 or more tables with PDO. I checked [documentation](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#Main_info) but can't find anything helpful. Maybe I am missing some part of Moodle. Let's say I want to get all users enrolled to the specified course.
Is there any way to make something similar to this:

```
$users = get_records(['course', 'user'], 'course.id = user.course_id');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got replied from [Moodle forum](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=357112#p1441036):

> No.
>
> The DB API is there to simplify many common situations (e.g. getting
>   one or more records from a single table), but if you need to gather
>   data from more than one table at once, then you need to use
>   `$DB->get_records_sql()` (or similar).
>
> However, if you want a list of users in a particular course, then use
>   the `get_enrolled_users()` function, rather than trying to manually
>   write the SQL query for it.